# Powershell Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I was wondering it is possible to use Set-DhcpServerv4Reservation in order to change the IP Address of a reservation. If not, is the only way to do so completely deleting the reservation and then recreating it with the new settings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @briantist I have not, but thats because I do not know how to set it up if you can change the IP, and the documentation only shows an example to use an IP. And I do not necessarily have the luxury to try as the server does not have computers I can test it on since its not mine.

Comment: @briantist I've tried it now... its not possible to do it unless you completely delete the reservation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first delete the reservation and then re add it using the preferred settings.

```
$newip="132.4.5.214"
$query = Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $scopeid -ComputerName $serverName | WHERE {$_.IPAddress.IPAddressToString-eq $testip}
        if($query.Name){
            $ip = $query.IPAddress.IPAddressToString
            Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName $serverName -IPAddress $ip
            Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $scopeid -ComputerName $serverName-IPAddress $newIP -ClientId $query.ClientId -Name $query.Name
}
```